# How do I eliminate the left-swipe Google Snapshot page from my home screen? (S21 Ultra)

Tags: google

Recently got a Samsung S21 Ultra.   When I swipe left from the home screen I get Google Assistant "Snapshot", which I have no use for.

So I disabled Google Assistant via **Google app > Settings > Google Assistant > General**

So now when I swipe left from the home screen I get an EMPTY page with Google Snapshot at the top!   I don't want ANYTHING left of the home page.   How do I get rid of that?

Comment: Maybe this function doesn't work if you change the launcher? Some functionalities are baked in with the default browser and don't work with third party browsers. You could try Nova launcher to check

Comment: The page left to the home screen is for sure part of the launcher app. Just use a different launcher.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an answer that worked on an earlier device, so should work on the S21.

The Snapshot that you see is simply a widget of the app.  Press and hold the Snapshot, a recycle bin icon will appear, drag the Snapshot to the bin.

That will leave you with an empty page.  You can add the launch icons or widgets of your choice.